# how to use context api in react in counter example?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-hooks, use-context

I am trying to use `context api` or use of `useContext`in my counter example.Actually I `initialize`  my value with `0` .On button click I want to `increase` the counter value ?But I am not able to do that.

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-spence-qbmps?file=/src/context.js

I took a example where `user` increase the counter to show loader similar to increase and decrease counter.

**but I am doing something wrong**

could you please tell me how I will increase and decrease the counter value using `context` api without using `redux`

```
import React, { useReducer, useContext, createContext } from "react";

const LoadingStateContext = createContext();
const LoadingDispatchContext = createContext();
const initialState = {
  loadingCount: 0
};

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SHOW_LOADER":
      return { ...state, loadingCount: state.loadingCount + 1 };
    case "HIDE_LOADER":
      return { ...state, loadingCount: state.loadingCount - 1 };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

function LoadingProvider({ children }) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const showLoading = () => dispatch({ type: "SHOW_LOADER" });
  const hideLoading = () => dispatch({ type: "HIDE_LOADER" });

  const actions = { showLoading, hideLoading };

  return (
    <LoadingStateContext.Provider value={state}>
      <LoadingDispatchContext.Provider value={actions}>
        {children}
      </LoadingDispatchContext.Provider>
    </LoadingStateContext.Provider>
  );
}

function useLoadingState() {
  const context = useContext(LoadingStateContext);
  if (context === undefined)
    throw Error('"useErrorState" should be used under "ErrorProvider"!');

  return context;
}

function useLoadingActions() {
  const context = useContext(LoadingDispatchContext);
  if (context === undefined)
    throw Error(
      '"useErrorActions" should be used under "ErrorDispatchContext"!'
    );

  return context;
}

export { LoadingProvider, useLoadingState, useLoadingActions };
```

I also saw this tutorial

https://medium.com/@seantheurgel/react-hooks-as-state-management-usecontext-useeffect-usereducer-a75472a862fe
but below codepen is not working ?

Comment: Your codesandbox code is not complete pls fix it

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-spence-qbmps?file=/src/context.js

Comment: sorry .please check now

Answer (score 0):

You are not consistent with the naming:

```
const { loadingCount } = useLoadingState();
const { showLoading, hideLoading } = useLoadingActions();
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-drake-18t12?file=/src/counter.js